# Run tests in pytest in order of execution time

Tags: python, pytest

I want to run tests in pytest according to the execution time of the last run. Is there a plugin to do so? Or how would you write the plugin?

I guess I need to cache the execution times of the last run, but I'm not sure on how to do that.

Also, I'd like to run using the --ff option, giving priority to tests that failed first, and then ordering by execution time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote my own plugin: https://github.com/david26694/pytest-slow-last

You can install it via:

```bash
pip install pytest-slow-last
```

and run

```bash
pytest --slow-last
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such plugin but, as you said, you can write your own.

Since pytest plugin is just a set of hooks and fixtures may be you can go just with some hooks in your `conftest.py` file.

First of all you need to learn how to write your hooks [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html#hook-function-validation-and-execution).

Then, referencing to [this page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#hooks) find hooks that you need.

I believe that algorithm will be something like this:

1. Run tests
2. After test execution collect test results to some file (you will need test's full name, duration and status) OR use files generated by some pytest reporting plugin.
3. Run tests again
4. During pytest initialization stage register new command line option `-ff`
5. During pytest collection stage read saved file and `-ff` parameter value and change the test's execution order according to desired rules.

To implement this thing some of these hooks may be useful:

- [pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) -
  Register argparse-style options and ini-style config values, called once at the beginning of a test run. Must be used to implement **step 4**.
- [pytest_collection_modifyitems](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) - Called after collection has been performed. May filter or re-order the items in-place. Must be used to implement **step 5**. Test order must be changed in `items` object (list).
- [pytest_report_teststatus](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_report_teststatus) -  Must be used to implement **step 2**. `report` object will contain `duration`, `outcome` (str) or `passed` (bool), `nodeid` (which is basically the full name).